# Base address defaulting to localhost

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to use the @@ action to retrieve the address of a page using the corresponding controller :

```
href="@@{Application.validateEmail(userSession.email,userSession.validationKey)}"
```

Well, I do get the correct address, however the base is always localhost:9000. I tried to add this line into my application.conf `%my-dev-mode.application.baseUrl=http://<my_address>`but nothing changer.

Does any one have a clue why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play 1.2.4 (and I still believe it is true), Play got the base URL from the request header. For example, if you access your action using `http://127.0.0.1:9000/someroute` instead of `http://localhost:9000/someroute` you should get 127.0.0.1 in the generated URL when using @@.

Comment: So if my actual site is running on multiple servers (with the same url), I still get the same url no matter what server is the client linked to, right ?

Comment: yes, exactly. the baseURL was added to the config because I raised a bug that absolute URLs failed in Jobs, because they were not linked to an HTTP request. So baseURL is only used when http header is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting your application with `--%my-dev-mode` ? Does it work without the key?